# Arduino IDE, Underlying Code and Libraries

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm trying to better understand what is going on behind the Arduino IDE. First off I am no expert in C or writing firmware to boards but do have experience in real development.

I see currently the Arduino IDE is one big vast library we first select our board.
What I don't understand is where are our header files? The source files for the board you select?

Not only that we use a number of functions already detected within the IDE where are these located also is any of this code editable?

I had a look through the Arduino directory and most of this stuff looks like its Java I was hoping for C files. Thanks for any links, help or info anyone can give.

Comment: In IDE, click File, Preference.  In 4th line ("Show verbose output during:"), check the "Compilation" box.  On the next compile you'll see a lot of the paths.   Then turn it back off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the [source code](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino). Specifically look at `Arduino.h`, `main.cpp` and `wiring*`.

These files should also be present in the Arduino application folder somewhere, but you'll have to go through quite a few subfolders to find them.

The different boards have different .h file that will specify the pin-numbers and other chip specific data.

The "auto detect" functionality is done by `keywords.txt` files. At least for libraries. That way if you install a new library with keywords.txt file, the library functions-names are recognized.

The processes of taking all these files, and the users code, and compile it all whole story on it's own.